# javascript object key-value loop setInterval

Tags: javascript, loops

```
var coords={100: 100, 120: 120, 140: 140, 160:160, 180:180};

for (var key in coords) {
    console.log(key + ' - ' + coords[key]);
}
```

I have variable `coords` and for loop that prints out pairs of numbers like this:

> 100 - 100
>
> 120 - 120
>
> 140 - 140
>
> 160 - 160
>
> 180 - 160

I need `setInterval` or something to console each pair of numbers every second.
I tryed to add setInterval, but in this case the code prints all the numbers every second, not individual pairs.

Comment: Can you show us how you tried to use `setInterval` in your code please?

Comment: var coords={100: 100, 120: 120, 140: 140, 160:160, 180:180};
 
function getCoord() {
 for (var key in coords) {
   console.log(key + ' - ' + coords[key]);
  }
 }
 
setInterval(getCoord, 1000);

Comment: Hello. I put for loop inside function called getCoor and then called it usind setInterval(getCoord, 1000); But it's not correct logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear, but I think this is what you are asking for. It will print the first pair, wait, print the next pair, wait, and so on.

```
var coords = {/* coords */};
var keys = Object.keys(coords);
var index = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log(keys[index] + " - " + coords[keys[index]]);
    index++;
    if(index == keys.length) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 3000);
```

As a side note, [the order of values in Javascript objects are not guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). If the order you print the coordinates matters or even if `coordinates` actually represents a list of coordinates, it would be better to make `coordinates` an array of pairs of numbers instead of an object. Additionally, the keys of the object are converted to strings, which is something you do not want with numerical coordinates.

Comment: After second reading the question I too agree this is the actual answer +1